# How to skip invalid servers in SQLCMD mode in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I am running sqlcmode mode in ssms agains multiple servers:

```
:CONNECT SERVER1
script
GO
:CONNECT SERVER2
script
GO
:CONNECT SERVER3
script
GO
```

etc, however when server2 is not accessible it stops there and won't connect to server3, is there a way to ignore connection errors in SQLCMD mode?

Answer (score 0):

`:CONNECT` related exceptions stop script execution.

As a possible workaround for SQLCMD mode:

```
!!sqlcmd -SServerA -Q"select 1"

!!sqlcmd -SServerB -Q"select 2"

!!sqlcmd -SServerC -Q"select 3"
```

**Update:** removed `:on error ignore`